# Singular Value Decomposition in Lua

Tags: lua, svd

I am looking for a function, similar to Numpy in Python for SVD.

```
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(Mx)
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can create own data-structure.

Comment: @hjpotter92: `svd` is one of the most popular approach. I think it should be available already. Isn't it?

Comment: https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#eigenvalues-svd-linear-system-solution

Comment: Seems so complicated, just for `svd`!!! Couldn't understand it.

Comment: My point exactly. Writing you own structure would be easier.